# Using relatedTo with 'Users' field

Tags: users

I have a sports site I'm building where each team is set up as a user within a 'team' member group.  I have a channel called 'Schedule' that has only 2 fields; a user field to relate the schedule to a team and then a table for the list of games.

On the front-end if I have a profile page for each team (ie: `http://www.example.com/{username}`).  I'm having trouble outputting the correct schedule based on the username in the URL?

Comment: Are you able to pull a User from the username? Have you set up this page in your Routes?

Comment: Let's have a look at your templates too! That would help us help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how your templates look, I can only give you a basic example:

```
{% set team    = craft.users.username(craft.request.lastSegment) %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('schedules').relatedTo(team) %}
```

This should give you all entries in the `schedules` channel which have a relation to the `team` username.